# How can a userscript detect when a user navigates to a new page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a userscript that modifies the UI of a browser game I'm playing. But I've run into a problem where my UI elements that I add to the page go away when I navigate to a new page.

I've tried several methods to try and detect when a new page has loaded and recreate my UI elements. But I've been unable to do it.

Here are the methods I've tried:

```
$(window).on("load", function(){
    console.log("loaded new page");
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    console.log("loaded new page");
}); 

$(window).on("hashchange", function(){
    console.log("loaded new page");
 });
```

None of them ever get triggered when I change to a new page.

Can anyone tell me why none of these are triggering from my userscript? And how might I correctly detect a new page has loaded?

For reference, the browser game I'm trying to detect this on is https://talibri.com/.

edit:
I have included the following in the `@match` on my script.

```
 @match        *://talibri.com/*
 @match        *://www.talibri.com/*
```

EDIT:
So last night I thought I had it working thanks to Vignesh's suggestion, but nope! It actually still wasn't working. So this morning and afternoon I've been trying ANYTHING I could think of to get this to work, and I finally figured it out.

Apparently the page I'm trying to parse is using Ruby on Rails Turbolinks which does some weird stuff with page loading.

To fix my problem I just did the following code:

```
$(window).on("turbolinks:load", function(){
    console.log("loaded new page");
});
```

I also did both load and turbolinks:load to handle both of the load events:

```
$(window).on("load turbolinks:load", function(){
    console.log("loaded new page");
});
```

Comment: what have you included in the `@match` in the userscript ?

Comment: You first define a global variable that will set the default value as the home page. You should trigger a function on click on the menu and in that menu. A function updates global variable and it is the way you may also find that in which you are at present.

Comment: \*://talibri.com/\*
\*://www.talibri.com/\*

Comment: is it working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works.

Need to include `*` at the end.

`// @match        http*://talibri.com/*`

The above detects all the pages in `talibri.com`

`https://talibri.com/`

`https://talibri.com/splash/world`

`https://talibri.com/splash/patches`

`https://talibri.com/users/sign_in`

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         My Utility
// @namespace    VigneshRaja_UserScripts
// @version      0.1
// @description  My Companion
// @author       Vignesh Raja
// @include      http*://talibri.com/*
// @grant        GM_setClipboard
// @grant        GM_openInTab
// ==/UserScript==
```